# passing parameter to configuration value in magento

Tags: magento, configuration, footer

I want my copyright text would be like this:

My Company ©  2001 - `$thisYear`

To edit copyright text, I select System > Configuration > Design, and then edit the text in Copyright text field, but how to pass the parameter `$thisYear` to the Copyright text field?

Comment: Tell me why vote down, please?

Comment: please check my suggestion below as answer.

Comment: I suggest to update the title of the question to "Copyright year at footer should update dynamically from configurations"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please enter `My Company © 2001 - %s` in the configurations `System > Configuration > Design` and then edit  `footer.phtml`, and use the following code:

```
<address><?php echo $this->__( $this->getCopyright(), date('Y')) ?></address>
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot simply put a variable into a system configuration field in magento! :)

Comment: I upvoted MTM for this nice solution - also i insist its not possible to put a variable into a system configuration field directly.